# Git pull claims new local file will be overwritten

Tags: git, merge

I have created a local file.

```
user@box:/project$ git status
On branch development
Your branch and 'origin/development' have diverged,
and have 2 and 6 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

      new file:   components/shared/some_utils.py

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

       modified:   components/shared/some_utils.py
```

However, when I do a pull I get this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    components/shared/some_utils.py
```

I have confirmed that this file is completely local is not coming in from remote.  I cannot understand how or why git would overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to commit your file you can do the alternative :

```
git stash
git pull 
git stash apply
```

Answer (score 0):

Git pull changes the position of the HEAD pointer and will over write changes you have made locally. The solution to this is that you should commit your local changes before pulling.

Do this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "your message"
git pull
```

That should work.

Comment: But it leaves other files alone.  Omitted from the output above were three other modified files which git was not concerned about.  It normally only flags files which 'would' be overwritten by incoming changes.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: If a file is seen by git as modified, then git is already tracking it. Once git is tracking the file and you do a pull without committing changes to the modified files, it will over write the changes. But if a new file is created and not tracked by git, it shouldn't be over written.

Comment: Does this not assume there is something upstream to overwrite it with?  If there is nothing upstream that would need to overwrite the file it seems that git normally leaves uncommitted changes alone.  I frequently have uncomitted files in my git status, but can successfully pull.    What struck me as odd here is that they cannot possibly be incoming changes for this file as it's brand new and I know no-one else has added the same file.

Comment: The main reason I asked this question is not because it creates much of a problem for me, I intend to commit it, but rather that I am seeing some rather strange git behaviours in general regarding incoming changes.  For example, doing a "git diff" on a file, deciding to discard the changes with "git checkout" and then git flagging the file as a conflict when doing a pull.  Other things such as a local file showing as having no local changes, but being identical to the remote branch and still being flagged as being overwritten.  We are suffering code loss from DB Schemas etc.